# How to do menu with submenu in tableview iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, menu, submenu

Hi I have to do menu with submenu in table view. Menu look like: 
`1. News
---|1.1 
---|1.2
---|1.3
2. Weather
3. Ads
4. Cinema`

Data to menu is download from server.

I have to do move cell in this menu.

Which framework used?

Comment: please try the answer and let me know

Comment: searchableWordsList and menu is nsdictionary?

Comment: My mistake, i have edited the answer. what is your menus format

Comment: For me the data was like ,menus are like an array of dictionaries ,with each dictionary containing keys @"title" and @"submenu",again this submenu is another array of dictionaries containing keys like @"title" and etc

Comment: Do you have example project?

Comment: is ur menus that u receive from the server in this format [
  {
    "submenus": [
      "SN",
      "BD",
      "BE",
      "TY"
    ],
    "title": "News"
  },
  {
    "submenus": [
      "SN",
      "BD",
      "BE",
      "TY"
    ],
    "title": "Weather"
  },
  {
    "submenus": [
      "SN",
      "BD",
      "BE",
      "TY"
    ],
    "title": "Ads"
  }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return self.menus.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return  55;;

}

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 70;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [[self.menu objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"submenus"];
}


- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 70)];

headerView.backgroundcolor = [UIColor clearcolor];

UILabel *menuTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, tableView.frame.size.width - 5, 60)];
menuTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
menuTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:68.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];;
menuTitleLabel.text = [[[self.menus objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"title"] uppercaseString];
menuTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:16.0];
[menuTitleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[headerView addSubview:menuTitleLabel];

return headerView;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSArray *submenuArray  = [[self.menus objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"submenus"];;

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
MenuCell *cell = (MenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
cell.title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:16.0];
cell.title.text = [subMenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.title.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:68.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
return cell;

}
```

Comment: Create a custom uitableviewcell  MenuCell,load the menus from the server to menus array,reload the tablew.The view for header will contain your required datas like News,Weather etc and in the cell for row method prepare the submenu respectively

Answer (score 1):

Look at using the `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. Consider using a different table section for each menu section and set the indentation based on `indexPath.row > 0` (assuming 2 levels in the menu).